# How can i get WWDC10 sample code? (104. Designing Apps with Scroll Views)

Tags: iphone, ios, wwdc

i saw WWDC10 session "104, Designing Apps with Scroll Views".

and i want get sample code using demo. but i can't find it.

i found "ScrollViewSuite" but it's not same demo.

it's not provided?

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question. http://stackoverflow.com/q/3111855/458922

Comment: Robot K. i already download "WWDC 2010 code samples". but code samples not include "Designing Apps with Scroll Views".

Comment: Just in case anyone else was looking for the same "PhotoScroller" demo as me, it can be found here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/navigation/index.html#topic=Sample+Code&section=Resource+Typeshttps://developer.apple.com/library/archive/navigation/index.html#topic=Sample+Code&section=Resource+Types

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Login to http://developer.apple.com with your Apple developer ID.
- Click on videos.
- Choose any one of the option HD/Standerd to view in iTunes.
- In iTunes you can find the link at Bottom right to the Sample code

You can find all WWDC 2010 sample code there

> **EDIT: Sample code is under
>   wwdc10samplecode\WWDC10-SampleCode\iOS\PhotoScroll**

[image]