# WWDC 2010 Session 104 Sample Code

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate, wwdc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WWDC 2010 Sample Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111855/wwdc-2010-sample-code)

Where I can found the FrogsDemo sample code from WWDC 2010 Session 104?

Comment: I voted to close, but I checked and the example used in this session is not in the bundled source supplied for the WWDC sessions.  However, all of the critical code for the demo is shown onscreen during that session, so you can simply transcribe what they show you.  Also, they do provide other scroll view samples that illustrate the concepts demonstrated in that session.

Comment: The PhotoScroller app is the application you are looking for. It is in the sample code and can be downloaded from the iOS developer site. It's not called FrogsDemo but it is the same application. I understand your confusion and would vote to reopen if I could.

Comment: @BradLarson There is actually a lot of code not shown during the video. Most of the CATiledLayer code is not shown. The presenter states "you can get this from the sample code later"

Comment: @hipplar - Oops, I guess I remembered the session wrong.  At least you can get the code somewhere.